# VS2010 Performance differences when debugging/profiling

Tags: .net, performance, visual-studio-2010, optimization

[See edit @ the bottom - the problem may not be what I initially thought]

Hi All,

I'm writing a graphics library which handles a number of filters/effects including blur.

I've been trying to optimise my code and have come across something I don't understand...

When I run the code *without* the performance wizard, a simple 3x3 blur on a small image can take a few seconds (far longer than it should). If I break execution during this delay, I get:

```
No Source Available
System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.WindowThreadProc() + 0xc2 bytes
```

The address is consistent between runs/clicks

If I run the code via the Performance Wizard, the blur effect happens with **no** noticeable delay.

I can see that the CPU is at 50% (dual core CPU, no multi-threading ATM so maxing out 1 core) for the duration of the blur whichever method I use to start my app.

If I scale up the complexity of the blur to get noticeable delays, I'd guesstimate that attaching the profiler improves performance by at least 2 orders of magnitude.

I've tried switching from Debug to Release build definition and get the same result.

Can someone explain to me why my code would run faster with a profiler attached? It feels like I'm making a silly mistake somewhere

**EDIT:**

Scenarios/Speeds:

- On Windows XP:

  - Debugging within VS: **Slow**
  - Profiling within VS: Fast
  - Debug/Release Build outside VS: Fast

I then switched to my second machine and got ...

- On Windows 7:

  - Debugging within VS: **Fast**
  - Profiling within VS: Fast
  - Debug/Release Build outside VS: Fast

Which seems to indicate I've mis-identified the problem - It's not that the profiler is improving things, it's that debugging in the IDE is killing it... I didn't initially suspect debugging was the issue as I started developing on the Win7 machine which had no issues then switched to the XP machine and assumed the speed change was due to hardware differences. It wasn't until I started profiling that I saw how quickly it ran...

Comment: Does the same occur when you just run the application outwith visual studio? Does it still have the same delay.

Comment: @kyndigs - Good point - I've edited the Q to give a detailed answer

Comment: I think you've solved your own problem man.  The debugger kills performance.  Which is OK IMO, since it's not for performance testing.  I'm actually glad of your detailed results there, as it shows "not a bad hit" for the profiler, which is very useful.

Comment: @Kevin - Agree with your conclusion about the profiler but am not 100% happy with the debugger - Why the performance difference between platforms? Perhaps Win7 has some additional functionality to minimise impact? I'd be interested to know...

Comment: Im sure Windows 7 is more optimised to cope with the .NET framework and if its visual studio 2010 it was also optimised for Windows 7 and not XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a total guess, but is visual studio running with administrative rights, but your program is not?  Basically, are you getting the UAC promotion dialog when launching visual studio, and thus if run through the debugger/profiler there, you can max a CPU, but a "user-space" process may not be allowed to?  A related question would be to ask if you're getting the performance "improvement" when running with the debugger (not profiler) or not.

Total guesswork, but may be a place to start looking.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Running on XP for the purposes of this test (I'll add that to the Q) so no UAC. I'm not near the machine so can't test with/without debugger - will get back to you this evening. Nice idea for a place to start, thanks.

Comment: UAC comment didn't seem to be correct but you got the debugger bit exactly. Thanks